# POLYMER: Data binding between two custom elements

Tags: data-binding, polymer

I have a custom element called "datasource.html" which loads a json using iron-ajax. Now, I want to use the JSON data into "app.html" and eventually into "categories.html"

Then in app.html, I want to use this same value of myattr and transfer the same to categories.html.

Now, datasource.html prints the data on screen but categories.html shows nothing on the page.

**What I want is that I load data in datasource.html once and then use the data anywhere in the project.**

Trying to figure this out for last 2 days. Still got nothing.

Thanks in advance.

Here is my index.html file

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title></title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
<script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>

<link rel="import" href="lgelements/datasource.html">
<link rel="import" href="lgelements/app.html">
</head>

<body>
<dom-module id="landing-page" attributes="myattr">
    <template>
        <lg-datasource myattr="{{myattr}}"></lg-datasource>
        <lg-app myattr="{{myattr}}"></lg-app>
    </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
Polymer({
    is: "landing-page",
});
</script>
<landing-page></landing-page>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is datasource.html

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">
<dom-module id="lg-datasource" attributes="myattr" hidden>
<template>
<iron-ajax url="../data.json" auto handleAs="json" last-response="{{myattr}}"></iron-ajax>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[myattr]]">
        <a href="[[item.url]]" target="_blank">
            <h1>[[item.name]]</h1>
        </a>
    </template>
  </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
Polymer({
is: "lg-datasource",
});
</script>
```

Here is my app.html

```
<link rel="import" href="categories.html">
<dom-module id="lg-app" attributes="myattr" vertical layout>
<template is="auto-binding">

    <h1>[[myAttr]]</h1>
    <lg-categories myattr="{{myattr}}"></lg-categories>
</template>
</dom-module>

<script>
Polymer({
    is: "lg-app",
});
</script>
```

And here is categories.html

```
<dom-module id="lg-categories" attributes="myattr">
<template is="auto-binding">
<h2>MY NAME IS MANIK</h2>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{myattr}}">
          <a href="[[item.url]]" target="_blank">
            <h1>[[item.name]]</h1>
        </a>
    </template>
</template>
</dom-module>
<script>
Polymer({
    is: "lg-categories",
});
</script>
```

Comment: You're mixing Polymer 1.0 syntax and that of Polymer 0.5. Try rewriting these codes to match that of version 1.0.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Neil. I'm very new to polymer. Could you please specify where have I used 0.5's syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Use double curly brackets {{}} when you use the item inside the element with is="dom-repeat". So change it to:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{myattr}}">
          <a href="{{item.url}}" target="_blank">
            <h1>{{item.name}}</h1>
        </a>
    </template>
```

Also you should expose the **myattr** as a property and remove the template in datasource.html file.

```
Polymer({
  is: "lg-datasource",
  properties : {
    myattr : Array
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have only skimmed your code, but I had the same kind of problem,... a child element that was the datasource and the parent that was supposed to display it. To get the data binding to work I needed to call _setPropertyName(data) in the child. Can't seem to find where this is documented but that's how its done internally in iron-ajax (look at the "loading" property).